# Node.js Socket.io wrong path

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm experimenting this issue at game.html

```
GET http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found) game.html:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined game.html:3
```

My game.html file

```
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
     var socket = io.connect('http://localhost/game.html');
     socket.on('news', function (data) {
     console.log(data);
     socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
    });
    </script>
```

And my server.js

```
    var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(5667);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/game.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
});
```

It was working fine when I was using index.html instead of game.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not retrieving `game.html` from the Node app, because the `socket.io.js` file seems to be retrieved from an HTTP port running on port 80 whereas your Node app is running on port 5667.

Also, your client-side connection string is incorrect:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost/game.html');
```

That also tries to contact a server on port 80 (and I don't know what `game.html` is doing there).

So try this:

- change the client-side connection string to `var socket = io.connect();`
- start your Node app
- open `http://localhost:5667/` in your browser

And see if that works better.